# Python : reduce execution time, optimize loops

Tags: python, optimization, execution-time

```
def SSIM_compute(files,WorkingFolder,DestinationAlikeFolder,DestinationUniqueFolder,results, start_time):
        
        NumberAlike=0
        loop=1
        while True:
            files=os.listdir(WorkingFolder)
            if files==[]:
                break
            IsAlike=False
            CountAlike=1
            print("Loop : "+str(loop)+" --- starttime : "+str(time.time()-start_time))
            
            for i in range (1,len(files)):
                #print("\ti= "+str(i)+" : "+str(time.time()-start_time))
                img1=cv2.imread(WorkingFolder+"/"+files[0])
                img2=cv2.imread(WorkingFolder+"/"+files[i])
                x1,y1=img1.shape[:2]
                x2,y2=img2.shape[:2]
                x=min(x1,x2)
                y=min(y1,y2)         
                img1=cv2.resize(img1,(x,y),1)
                img2=cv2.resize(img2,(x,y),1)
                threshold=ssim(img1,img2,multichannel=True)
                if threshold>0.8:
                    IsAlike=True
                    if os.path.exists((WorkingFolder+"/"+files[i])):
                        shutil.move((WorkingFolder+"/"+files[i]),DestinationAlikeFolder+"/alike"+str(NumberAlike)+"_"+str(CountAlike)+".jpg") 
                        CountAlike+=1
                        #results.write("ALIKE : " +files[0] +" --- " +files[i]+"\n")
                        results.write("ALIKE : /alike"+str(NumberAlike)+"_0"+".jpg --- /alike"+str(NumberAlike)+"_"+str(CountAlike)+".jpg  -> "+str(threshold))
                        
            if IsAlike:
                if os.path.exists((WorkingFolder+"/"+files[0])):
                    shutil.move((WorkingFolder+"/"+files[0]),DestinationAlikeFolder+"/alike"+str(NumberAlike)+"_0"+".jpg")  
                    NumberAlike+=1
            else :
                if os.path.exists((WorkingFolder+"/"+files[0])):
                    shutil.move((WorkingFolder+"/"+files[0]),DestinationUniqueFolder)
            loop+=1
```

I have this code that must compare images to determine if they are identical or if some of them were modified (compression, artefact, etc...).

So, to check if two images are strictly similar, I just compute and compare their respective hashes (in another function not shown here), and to check if they are similar I compute the SSIM on those two files.

The next part is where the trouble begins : when I test this code on a quiet small set of pictures (approx. 50), the execution time is decent, but if I make the set bigger (something like 200 pictures), the execution time becomes way too high (several hours) as expected considering I have two imbricated for loops.

As I'm not very creative, has anybody ideas to reduce the time execution on a larger dataset ? Maybe a method in order to avoid those imbricated loops ?

Thank you for any provided help :)

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing each image with every other image - you could pull reading the first image `img1` out, of the for loop and just do it once per file.

But as you're comparing each file with every other file that's going to slowdown as O(N^2/2) i.e. 200 will be 8x slower than 50. Maybe you could resize to a much smaller size like 64x64 which would be much quicker to compare with `ssim()`, and only if similar at that small size do a full-size comparison?

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I'll try it and update the post with the time gained. I was also thinking about using threading after reading some articles, if I managed to implement it, I'll give news about it also